# ¿Qué significa instanciar una variable en lugar de una clase?

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo php y he visto que las instancias de las clases se crean de la forma tradicional que yo conocia:

```
$intancia = new MiClase();
```

Sin embargo yo me he encontrado en ejemplos de codigo cosas como esta que me han roto los esquemas:

```
$instancia = new $unaVariable();
```

Y eso es lo que no entiendo.  ¿Como funciona eso de instanciar una variable?

Comment: Si la variable es una referencia a una clase, estás instanciando la clase a la que referencia.

Comment: podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como crear una variable que haga referencia a una clase?

Comment: No tiene misterio. `$ref = MiClase;`, y después, cuando haces `new $ref;` es como si hubieras hecho `new MiClase;`. Útil para "factorías" que deben instanciar objetos de una clase que puede variar (pueden recibir la clase como parámetro, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En PHP, como en otros lenguajes dinámicos (ej: python), las clases son en sí mismas un tipo de valor que puede asignarse a una variable.

Así, si tengo por ejemplo esta clase:

```
class Foo {
    function saludar() {
        print "Hola, soy una instancia de Foo\n";
    }
}
```

La siguiente asignación sería válida:

```
$variable = Foo;
```

Fíjate que no estoy instanciando la clase (pues no he usado `new`) sino que simplemente he asignado a `$variable` una referencia a la clase `Foo`. Ahora `Foo` y `$variable` vienen a ser sinónimos, por lo que sería válido hacer:

```
$instancia = new $variable();
```

Una utilidad de esto es poder pasar clases como parámetros e instanciar objetos de diferentes clases desde un mismo método. O hacer una factoría de objetos que decida qué clase instanciar en función de las condiciones que consideres apropiadas.

Fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    function saludar() {
        print "Hola, soy una instancia de Foo\n";
    }
}

class Bar {
    function saludar() {
        print "Hola, soy una instancia de Bar\n";
    }
}

function crear_objeto($clase){
    return new $clase;
}

$instancia1 = crear_objeto(Foo);
$instancia1 -> saludar();
$instancia2 = crear_objeto(Bar);
$instancia2 -> saludar();
?>
```

Si lo ejecutas verás que `$instancia1` es de la clase `Foo`, mientras que `$instancia2` es de la clase `Bar`, y el objeto se ha creado en la función `crear_objeto()` que recibe como parámetro la clase a instanciar.

Answer (score 1):

Instanciar es un concepto de la POO en cualquier lenguaje no solo en PHP, te pongo el ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Persona
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function datosPersona () {
        return $this->name.' '.$this->age;
    }
}

//instanciando

$humanoUno = new Persona("alfredo paz", 28);
echo $humanoUno->datosPersona();

$humanoDos = new Persona("Diana Perez", 32);
echo $humanoDos->datosPersona();
```

En el ejemplo anterior tengo una clase o plantilla de datos generica, en la cual reconozco que quialquier persona tiene un nombre y una edad.

Pero ¿qué pasa cuando quiero identificar a una o muchas personas con datos específicos?

Entonces creo una instancia que es permitirle a un objeto la representación de las propiedades(variables), métodos(funciones) que posee dicha clase; pero en este caso para hacer la identificación particular de un humano.

Para la pregunta que haces en especifico, la primer línea de código esta instanciando directamente una clase, la segunda línea de código esta accediendo directamente a un método que por dentro tiene esa clase, checa en el que código que escribí yo como le indico que acceda al método datosPersona puesto que la clase por si sola no me devolvera ningún valor en tanto yo no ejecute los métodos que por dentro tiene, ya que estos son los que poseen acciones específicas que hará dicha clase